# Thread.interrupt () doesn't work

Tags: java, android

Hy!

My Thread.interrupt doesn't work.

Code (us is  global):

```
//Call

us = new UpdateState(params, hup);
            us.start();

//Interupt
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId()== R.id.stopthread)
        {
            Log.e("Kill", "Kill");
            us.interrupt();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Class:

```
package android.skiptvad;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.NoCopySpan.Concrete;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class UpdateState extends Thread {

    public List<NameValuePair> params;
    public Handler handler;
    public Handler ins;

    public UpdateState(List<NameValuePair> params, final Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.params = params;
        this.ins = new Handler (){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                if (msg.obj.toString()!= null)
                {
                    JSONParse json = null;
                    try 
                    {       
                            Message msg2 =new Message();
                            Log.e("Channel_State_Update",msg.obj.toString());
                            json = new JSONParse(msg.obj.toString());
                            String state = json.getChannelState();
                            Log.e("Channel_State_Send",state);
                            msg2.obj = state;
                            handler.sendMessage(msg2);

                    } 
                    catch (final Exception e) 
                    {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            while (true)
            {
                if (!this.isInterrupted())
                {
                    HttpConnection con = new HttpConnection(params, "http://surfkid.redio.de/getChannelState", this.ins);
                    con.start();
                    try {
                        Log.e("Sleep", "Begin");
                        UpdateState.this.sleep(5000);
                        Log.e("Sleep", "End");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("Sleep", "Error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }




            //super.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Log:

```
02-15 18:50:30.317: ERROR/Sleep(10696): End
02-15 18:50:30.347: ERROR/Sleep(10696): Begin
02-15 18:50:30.677: ERROR/Channel_State_Update(10696): {"responseData":{"channelState":"0"},"responseDetails":null,"responseStatus":200}
02-15 18:50:30.677: ERROR/Channel_State_Send(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:30.677: ERROR/UPDATE(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:35.347: ERROR/Sleep(10696): End
02-15 18:50:35.357: ERROR/Sleep(10696): Begin
02-15 18:50:35.897: ERROR/Channel_State_Update(10696): {"responseData":{"channelState":"0"},"responseDetails":null,"responseStatus":200}
02-15 18:50:35.897: ERROR/Channel_State_Send(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:35.897: ERROR/UPDATE(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:36.868: ERROR/Kill(10696): Kill
02-15 18:50:36.878: ERROR/Sleep(10696): Error
02-15 18:50:36.908: ERROR/Sleep(10696): Begin
02-15 18:50:37.427: ERROR/Channel_State_Update(10696): {"responseData":{"channelState":"0"},"responseDetails":null,"responseStatus":200}
02-15 18:50:37.427: ERROR/Channel_State_Send(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:37.427: ERROR/UPDATE(10696): 0
02-15 18:50:41.909: ERROR/Sleep(10696): End
02-15 18:50:41.927: ERROR/Sleep(10696): Begin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to break a loop when thread is interrupted:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!this.isInterrupted()) { // Exit when thread's interrupt flag is set
        HttpConnection con = new HttpConnection(params, "http://surfkid.redio.de/getChannelState", this.ins);
        con.start();
        try {
            Log.e("Sleep", "Begin");
            UpdateState.this.sleep(5000);
            Log.e("Sleep", "End");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Sleep", "Error");
            e.printStackTrace();

            // Restore interrupt flag after catching InterruptedException
            // to make loop condition false
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To explain further axtavt's answer:  When you catch InterruptedException, Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() gets reset to false.  At the end of catching the InterruptException, you need to restore the flag so that the this.isInterrupted() will have the correct value.

Comment: I would actually suggest 'break'ing the loop rather than re-asserting the interrupt status.  In this particular example I would consider the loop to be the consumer of the interrupt so when it exits the interrupt status should be false.  Doing the above the interrupt status will be true so if this Thread were to be reused the interrupt status will still be present.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to happen? You have the interrupt exception in a massive while loop :) You need to write break; inside the exception part for it to exit the loop. The `if !this.isInterrupted()` line only makes the loop extremely tight by eliminating the code inside, but the loop is still there on the outside.