# How to stop background thread, `interupt` not working

Tags: android, multithreading

Consider this example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Sleep for 5000ms
      // Show toast message
    }
  });
```

Now I will start this thread on button click in MainActivity and right after that I would exit the activity on back button press, but in overided method onBackPressed following code is implemented:

```
If(thread != null)
   thread.interupt();
finish();
```

After few seconds toast message is shown, why is that?

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008176/thread-interrupt-doesnt-work) and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791361/thread-not-interrupting) you will find some explanations. consider using `AsyncTask` in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interrupt, clears the `interrupt` status of your thread and will cause the `InterruptedException` to be thrown. So if your thread is sleepin, and while it is asleep, you call `interrupt`, it will be woken up, and the execution flow will continue from the instruction that follows the catch block. Assuming you have something really simple like:

```
public void run() {
   try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackThreace();
   }
   runOnUiThread(TOAST);
}
```

or

```
public void run() {
   while(true) {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackThreace();
      }
      runOnUiThread(TOAST);
   }
}
```

both will shown the Toast even though you called interrupt()

Answer (score 0):

While [blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt) has already explained the reason why this happens, here is how you can get around the problem.

The best way to interupt a thread is to use a if-boolean-break method.
So if i were to re-write you code it would be along the following lines

onBackPressed:

```
isBackPressed = true;
```

inside the thread's run method:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         // Sleep for 5000ms
         if(!isBackPressed){
          // Show toast message
         }
       }
    });
```